# How to display the Details of the user after login page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Login Page:

[image]
This is my login page,in that page i have validate only user name and password.
Now I am Selecting Company Name and Giving Year as a input that is not validate simply it feeds the input value.My problem is i want display the company name and year to dashboard page at the top.

How i display the values in dashboard

```
 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
    $query = $this->db->get('company_name');    
    $data['PName']=$query->result_array();

     $this->load->view('admin/login',$data);
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
    redirect('Dashboard', 'refresh');
    //  $this->load->view('Dashboard');
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $password = $this->input->post('password');
   $year= $this->input->post('Year');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->User_model->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username,


       );

       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or passwords');
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: store these all information in the sessions and then you can show it anywhere in your dashboard or on any page

Comment: show me how you are posting your login form ? where you are getting your values in controller ? show me your controller code to get form values

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh i edit my question and i have post my controller code

Comment: @Roshan Yes after this page the company name and year of that user is want to display in the dashboard page

Comment: @Tom you could use session.

Comment: function index()
 {

if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')>2)

{
       $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
       $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     
      $data['results'] = $this->Search_model->searchbyname();
     $this->load->view('Dashboard', $data);
     //If no session, redirect to login page
   
}
else{
  redirect('login','refresh');
}
  
 }

Comment: This is dashboard controller code.

Comment: I don't know how to use for company name and year

Comment: there is too much confussion in your code 
$query = $this->db->get('company_name');  
Tell me something about this line what you exactly want to do in this case

Comment: you are selecting your company in login page and then posting it to your controller do you want to confirm it from the database ? or you want to show it in your dashboard direct by getting it in your controller from login page?

Comment: This is i am using company name a dropdown list for that data i am getting from database "company name"

Comment: it simply validate only username and password only'

Comment: I am just giving company name and year  as a input it does not check it is in database or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188095/discussion-between-tom-and-abdulrehman-sheikh).

Comment: It is not necessary to validate company name and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store your data in the sessions and for this your index function should be like this:

```
function index()
 {
       //This method will have the credentials validation
       $this->load->library('form_validation');

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');

       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {
         //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
        $query = $this->db->get('company_name');    
        $data['PName']=$query->result_array();

         $this->load->view('admin/login',$data);
       }
       else
       {
           $newdata = array(
                   'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
                   'Year'     => $this->input->post('Year'),
                   'company_name'     => $this->input->post('company_name')
               );
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);


            //Go to private area
            redirect('Dashboard', 'refresh');
        //  $this->load->view('Dashboard');
       }

 }
```

After that when you will redirect on your dashboard page, inside your dashboard view file in views, you can display your data by doing this:

```
<h1>Company: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('company_name'); ?> </h1>
<h1>User: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?> </h1>
<h1>Year: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('Year'); ?> </h1>
```

Comment: Without validate we can not pass this value or not?

Comment: Because i didn't save year in the table

Comment: you can pass it without validate bro

Comment: no problem, my code is not validating year and company_name from table. Its just stroring in session whatever you will select from the login form it will save it in session to display on dashboard

Comment: Your code save the all data in the session its right?

Comment: Yes its right. My code will save company name, username and year in the session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188096/discussion-between-abdulrehman-sheikh-and-tom).

Answer (score -1):

try to use session on your login page
so you can display the company name and year after you login

Comment: I used but it doesn't display the name simply shows error

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of the errors thanks

Comment: It give as undefined name

Comment: i think your problem will answer this site try to read this :)
https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/

Comment: undefined name so meaning the value of your  name is null or your name variable does not have a value

Comment: or try to save first your company and year in to your database then call it to the (controller) then pass it to the view (dashboard)